# Let $P$ be set of all polynomials with integer coefficients. Prove or disprove that the subset $Q= \{p \in P: p(2)=0\}$ forms a group under addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My claim is that yes it forms a group since

1. $(p_1+p_2)+p_3 = p_1+(p_2+p_3)$
   this is clearly true
2. $p+0 = 0+p = p$

   Zero polynomial also has 2 as a root and it acts as identity element for group $Q$.
3. $p+q = q+p= 0$
   for $q= -p$

   $q$ also belongs to set $Q$ because
   if $p(2) = 0$, then $0 = -p(2)$

   These are polynomials of root 2 but with the opposite signs of coefficients.

So, $Q$ is a group under addition.
Is my solution right or am I missing something really important. My only confusion is that zero polynomial has infinite roots. So, can I consider zero polynomial to be a polynomial with root 2? Does this means the zero polynomial belongs to $Q$? Because if not, then my solution falls apart

Comment: Your solution is right. You don't have to bother about the number of roots of the $0$ polynomial: what matters is that it is in the considered set.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)